# Modal Dialog fails to close on submission once ui.alert is Commented out

Tags: user-interface, google-apps-script, google-sheets, modal-dialog

Why should the Commenting out of a ui.alert cause the submission of a Modal Dialog to fail to close on submission? The functions still actually do what they are supposed to do, but the Dialog won't go away; you have to click the close button. I've been using Alert Boxes to troubleshoot my work, and now as I Comment them out, I find that there is one that I can't, without producing this problem.

The line in question is the only one commented out here:

```
function getStartFromDialog (form) {  
scriptProperties.getProperties();
var option1 = scriptProperties.getProperty('savedOption1');
var option2 = scriptProperties.getProperty('savedOption2');
var eRow = scriptProperties.getProperty('savedRow');
var tabName = scriptProperties.getProperty('savedTab');
var start = form.chosenStart; 
// ui.alert ('Chosen option is '+ start);
if (start == 'option1'){var adjustedStart = option1}
else {var adjustedStart = option2}
reactToUserEntryOfStart (adjustedStart,eRow); 
}
```

Here is the **index.htm** file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons1.css">

  <script>
    function submitForm() {
       google.script.run.getStartFromDialog(document.getElementById("startChoiceForm"));
      document.getElementById("form").style.display = "none";
    }
  </script>  

  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <div id="form">
      <? var offeredStart1 = offeredStarts[0]; var offeredStart2 = offeredStarts[1] ?>  
      <form id="startChoiceForm">
      <select name="chosenStart" id ="chosenStart">       
        <option value="option1"><?= offeredStart1 ?></option>
        <option value="option2"><?= offeredStart2 ?></option>
      </select>
    <div>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="action" onclick="submitForm()" >
      <input type="button" value="Close" onclick="google.script.host.close()" >
    </div> 
      </form>
    </div>  
  </body>
</html>
```

[This video](https://youtu.be/woaAUJ1-pHs) demonstrates:

1. Functions working;
2. My Commenting out that line *ui.alert ('Chosen option is '+ start)*;
3. Same procedure; now Dialog Box hangs.

The scripts allow the user to enter times in testUserEntTime!A3:A without typing a colon or specifying AM/PM, ie 325 for either 3:25am or 3:25pm. It automatically turns these entries into date-time values so that they are always sequential top-to-bottom, permitting no date-time to be earlier than the one before.

The dialog box is triggered by the entering of a time which has the same hour as the time above it, but earlier minutes.
In the video, the previous time is 4:55 am 9/5/2001  (formatted so only the time shows) and I am entering 450. This causes the script to ask whether I intend to indicate 4:50pm, or 4:50am on the next day, 9/6.

Thank you for your help; I'm bewildered.

[YouTube video demonstrating bug](https://youtu.be/woaAUJ1-pHs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I saw your sample Spreadsheet and your current script, in your situation, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
google.script.run.getStartFromDialog(document.getElementById("startChoiceForm"));
```

#### To:

```
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(google.script.host.close).getStartFromDialog(document.getElementById("startChoiceForm"));
```

- When `ui.alert ('Chosen option is '+ start);` is used in the function `getStartFromDialog`, the dialog is overwritten by `ui.alert`. By this, when the ok button is clicked, the dialog is closed. When you want to close the dialog by clicking submit button, `google.script.host.close` is run using `withSuccessHandler`.

#### Reference:

- [withSuccessHandler(function)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run#withSuccessHandler(Function))

Comment: Thank you, that was the fix!

Comment: @Atiq Zabinski Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.